# How to prevent Visual Studio's tsconfig detection from detecting tsconfigs in other projects?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, typescript1.8

**TypeScript Version:**

1.8.30.0

**Issue**

We have a solution with a number of web projects. We recently made a new project which used a tsconfig.json file.

This affected other projects to believe they had a tsconfig.json file, overriding our project typescript settings for those projects.

"One or more tsconfig.json files detected. Project properties are disabled."

I've checked and the project file itself does not contain any reference to any tsconfig.json files nor does the project folder contain a tsconfig file.

**Reproduce**

1. Create two new Web Api projects in same solution.
2. Add a typescript file to each project and accept that they are converted into a typescript project.
3. Add a tsconfig.json to the second project.
4. Open properties for the first project and go to the TypeScript Build Tab. Observe "One or more tsconfig.json files detected. Project properties are disabled."

How do I prevent a Visual Studio 2015 project from finding / detecting tsconfig.json files that are in another project folder?

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem also. I solved it by this:

1. Open Solution Explorer
2. Right click on the `tsconfig.json` file and choose 'Exclude From Project'.
3. You might see the `tsconfig.json` disappear from the Solution Explorer. In that case choose 'Show All Files' option from the top of the Solution Explorer toolbar.
4. Right click on the `tsconfig.json` and choose 'Include In Project'.

Comment: This does not resolve the issue. There is a bug in TypeScript which is scheduled for release in the 2.0 version. See [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8659) for more information.

Comment: I had to leave tsconfig.json excluded to make it work